# Firing off multiple API calls and updating local state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been working with a React app and I have run into a strange problem that I think I know the cause of but still can't find a way to fix it. I have an array of objects stored in a variable. Now I need to make an API call for each object in that array and update a certain field on it when I get a response from the call and then set the React component's state.

The API call receives one object at a time as a parameter so I need to make multiple API calls concurrently for every object in the state array. So lots of API calls and lots of state setter function calls.

The actual codebase is pretty complex so I've reconstructed a basic version of it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/yourAverageDeveloper/wtLhg6s0/36/). The API call will just add an `email` property on the existing object and then update the local state. I've simulated an API call using `setTimeout` and the API call function fires on component mount. When the loop finishes and all `setState` calls are done, what I get back on my browser is just the last object in the state variable and not all objects.

So I expect a response like

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Adam',
    email: 'adam@gmail.com'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Michael',
    email: 'michael@gmail.com'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Joseph',
    email: 'joseph@gmail.com'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Noah',
    email: 'noah@gmail.com'
  }
]
```

But what I get back instead is

```
[
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Noah',
    email: 'noah@gmail.com'
  }
]
```

I am guessing it's because of the asynchronous nature of the setter function of a React state variable. So, consecutive set state calls are all using the initial state because the previous ones haven't updated the state yet.

So, here's the problem, I need to make API calls for all entries in the array at once and as soon as I get the response, I need to update the state. Some answers that I've seen here talk about using Promise.all but I believe that will wait until all the API calls are resolved but that would affect my app's performance. Can't use a useEffect here either because I don't want to wait for one API call to finish and then call the next one. But maybe I am not understanding useEffect correctly?

I can't really think of any solution myself so I'd greatly appreciate your help in finding out another way around this.

Comment: Can you make the API calls and only update the state once all the calls have completed?

Comment: Please include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question (not only on JSFiddle).

Comment: @CVerica I can't unfortunately :( Can't wait for all the API calls to return data as the array will grow much larger overtime and it's going to really affect the app's performance in terms of how the users experience it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the `users` object as dependency to `useEffect()` otherwise it will access its initial state every time `fetchUsers()` is called.

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetchUsers();
  }, [users]);
```

The initial state of `users` is an empty array as defined here

```
const [users, setUsers] = React.useState([]);
```

You can read in the documentation

> If you pass an empty array ([]), the props and state inside the effect
> will always have their initial values.

Please read [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect).

Comment: But this just means every time I update the users, it will fetch all users again and that will fetch a user and call the updater function again so that's going to end up in an infinite loop. I just need to call it only once.

Comment: Yeah, that's right. This design is inherently flawed. I simply pointed out the fact that any variable that isn't passed as dependency to `useEffec()` will use its initial state every time. You should definitely not reassign the entire `users` object every time like you did in your fiddle. What about `Array.push()`?

Comment: Array.push would work perfectly fine if I could rerender the React component after it. Need to use the state setter function to trigger a rerender which would update the UI ☹️